# Job Service not getting started in Android marshmallow if low charge?

Tags: android, optimization, android-6.0-marshmallow, job-scheduling

I have a jobservice which has to repetitively run when device is connected to internet. It is running without any issues in Lollipop but the same job service is not executed in Marshmallow consistently. I suspect it is something to do with the battery percentage of device. Is Marshmallow doing any optimization on job service scheduling in low charge scenario? pls help me with this since it is inconsistent?

Answer (score 0):

```
jobScheduler.schedule(JobInfo.Builder(Random().nextInt(),
                ComponentName(this, NotificationJobService::class.java))
                .setExtras(bundle)
                .setRequiredNetworkType(JobInfo.NETWORK_TYPE_ANY)
                .build())

 setRequiredNetworkType(JobInfo.NETWORK_TYPE_ANY)
```

Set this as required type as you need Internet connection. When job service fulfill this criteria will do the job for you. But if battery is low system may try to kill some process before shutdown.